# Python GUI class structure calls

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt, qt-creator

Let's say for example I have two classes, `A` and `B`.

Class `A` is the one I called `class main` and `B` is a `GUI` class(lets say its called `class main_gui`).

GUI class contains method that initiates and sets all views, buttons and stuff called `setupUi`. Class is generated by `QtCreator`.

What else must my class have to make it sufficient to run `B` by itself or be called from other classes? I know that calling `__init__` is not mandatory but its a good idea. What must this function contain? Is `__main__` mandatory to make it runnable?

What must `__main__` contain? What must the constructor contain? I am stuck on calling classes and I can't find simple enough explanation or a simple enough sample code that i can implement in my case. Please explain for braindead human.

I am a Java developer but i am new in Python and its specifics. If it is possible to provide with some code samples (even pseudocode will do) you will be very helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if this is what your are looking for but :

A simple view :

```
class Home(QtWidgets.QFrame, Ui_home):
"""Home view."""

def __init__(self, parent=None):
    """Initializer."""
    super(Home, self).__init__()
    self._parent = parent
    self.setupUi(self)
```

Ui_home is the QtDesigner generated class

in my main i just create a QApplication and exec it :

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
```

Then i can call my home_controller or just create a home display my view:

```
home = Home()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Obviously this is a very simple exemple in a real app, you would have a class to handle the controller/ view creation but, this is as simple as that

Comment: so you are telling me that class Home is class `A` and to call the generated class `Ui_home` i have to extend it? I don't get it.

Comment: or class `Home` is the generated one?

Comment: to be more exact i need to generate a class from QtCreator and then call it as simple as possible from my (empty) main class. What does the main class call? What do i have to add to generated class so it can be callable? Because the only method inside generated class is `setupUI()`. I need to call it like `secondwindow = Generated()` and then `secondwindow.show()` or something like that. But to do so i need to add some code in the generated class...i hope i explained it good enough

Comment: Yes class A is Home and Ui_Home is your generated class, you have to extend it. This link explain how to create a simple window with PyQt : https://nikolak.com/pyqt-qt-designer-getting-started/

Comment: oh my god THANK YOU. Exactly what i needed. Keep an eye for SirenPlayer in the upcoming month or two :)

Comment: now when I think about it what happens if class B have to implement several click listerners for several window openings? Does it have to extend all of those window classes?

Comment: each window/component extends it generated class